# How to display a value where there is none in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

Is there a Djangotastic way to display a default value for a field in the admin when there isn't a value? Like 'n/a', but not to save that to the database?

When I set all the fields in the model below to readonly in the admin, the front-end display looks like the image at the bottom. It feels visually collapsed like it should have a value or a box or something. If there isn't an easy way to do what I am looking for, then is there another solution to make the front-end admin more clear for the user?

```
class Package(models.Model):
    packaging_format = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    package_delivery_pattern = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    package_delivery_comments = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    package_manifest_filename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    package_description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    package_naming_pattern = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**Screenshot of fields as displayed in the admin:**
[image: Screenshot of admin with readonly package fields]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening is that your actually saving a empty string `''` in your CharFields instead of `None` values (because of the `blank=True`). So the Django-admin is showing the string you saved in the db (in this case, nothing).

If you change your CharFields to `null=True` instead of `blank=True`, you will be saving `NULL` in your database instead of an empty string. And that way, you will get the behaviour you want.

**EDIT:** I know this solution is not recommended (following Django Docs), but that's the behaviour you wanted. Django-admin is just showing you the string you have in the database, which is `''`.

Another solution that comes to my mind is to modify the ModelAdmin for your `Package` model, something like:

```
class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['show_package_delivery_pattern', ...]

    def show_package_delivery_pattern(self, obj):
        if obj.package_delivery_pattern:
            return obj.package_delivery_pattern
        else:
            return 'N/A'
    # same with all your CharFields..
```

Comment: Docs say... " Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField unless you have an excellent reason. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL." | See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null | It seems to me that front-end admin display is not a good enough reason to message with the normalization of the dataset. Your thoughts?

Comment: Yes... modifying the model admin is kind of what I was thinking about. Thank you for updating your answer in response to my comment.

Answer (score 3):

As of Django 1.9 you can use [`empty_value_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.empty_value_display) at the site, model, or field level in the Django admin.  At the model level:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    empty_value_display = '---'
```